# get error messages from txt in php

Tags: php, forms, validation

i am currently working in a php project in which my client wants custom error messages for each time when he needs. So i want to store error messages in txt file and want to get those messages and show it in form validation. How to get those error messages in php. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: `you screwed up. pick a reason from: <?php readfile('error_msgs.txt') ?>`

Comment: parse_ini_file is good for this

Answer (score 1):

Start with the PHP documention. A quick Google search for "Read Text file in PHP" quickly brought this API info with some code you can use.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php